# Email in laravel shows variable instead of the value

Tags: php, laravel

I'm not sure what im missing here. So im working on emailing the client whenever there's an update however it doesnt show the value of variable or array passed here. So there's 3 files. First we start in the
controller.

```
$details = [
        'title'=> "[Helpdesk] Your ticket #{$ids[0]} has an update.",
        'body' => 'Your ticket request status has been updated.',
        'first_name' => $first_name,
        'last_name' => $last_name,
        'ticket_id' => $ids[0],
        'status' => $status,
        'agent_name' => $agent_name,
    ];
    

    //unrelated codes

    else if($status == 'open' || $status == 'assigned')
        {
            
            \Mail::to($email)->send(new \App\Mail\OpenAssignTicket($details));
        }
```

Now this is in the OpenAssignTicket file.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class OpenAssignTicket extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;
public $details;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($details)
{
    $this->details = $details;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject('Mail from Support')->view('emails.ticketAssignedOpen');
}
}
```

And finally this is in the resource view file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Support</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{$details['title']}}</h1>
<p>Dear {{$details['first_name'][0]}},</p>
<br>
<p>You ticket {{$details['ticket_id']}} has been updated to {{$details['status']}}. </p>
<br>
</p>Our Agent {{$details['agent_name'][0]}} is currently working on your request. We will get 
 back to you as soon as possible.</p>


<p>Thank you.</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p>From,</p>
<br>
<p>Support</p>
```

And in the email received it's exactly like that with the $details when it's supposed to show the value.

This is in another email that works.

Same controller file.

```
else{
       \Mail::to($email)->send(new \App\Mail\NewTicketMail($details));
      }
```

NewTicketMail file in the App/Mail
<?php

```
 namespace App\Mail;

 use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
 use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
 use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

 class NewTicketMail extends Mailable
 {
   use Queueable, SerializesModels;
   public $details;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($details)
{
    $this->details = $details;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject('Mail from VeecoTech Support')->view('emails.new_ticket_mail');
}
}
```

And finally resource view file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Support</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{$details['title']}}</h1>
<p>Dear {{$details['first_name'][0]}},</p>
<br>
<p>You ticket {{$details['ticket_id']}} has been updated to {{$details['status']}}.</p>


<p>Thank you.</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p>From,</p>
<br>
<p>Support</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The 2nd email works where values are shown.

Comment: What happens if you use the other view just to test it out?  Will it get your values then?

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear I meant swapping the New Ticket Mail view in place of the OpenAssignTicket view just to see if the problem is with the view.  If not, you can rule out your view being messed up and then you'll know the problem is in the controller or in your OpenAssignTicket Class.

Comment: @finiteloop after going through it again, i think it's the resource view problem but im not sure what. I copy pasted exactly the same thing from the working and it's still not working. I have called the view from the working app/mail file and it's not working. I have called the working view from the first app/mail file and it's working so it's gotta be something wrong with the view file.

Comment: It looks like your view file is missing `.blade.` suffix.

Comment: @Anton oh my god that did it, i cant believe it. I even checked to make sure the file extension was right but i must have missed it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of described behavior is missing `.blade` suffix in the name of the view file.

Comment: This is the solution. I cant believe i overlooked this. Thank you